# scanning a page in a directory with sscanf()  or Simple XML

Tags: php, jquery, simplexml, scanf

I'd like to scan the contents of a .php file sitting in my site's directory and then do some other things with the text inside it. I've also seen things like this done with jquery's `.html()`

How would I do this using `sscanf()` or Simple XML? or is that the correct approach at all?

Comment: Is hard to tell what you are looking for. Can you include some example of the your source code? and please indicate is written in which programming language.

Comment: Are you trying to parse the php file itself or its html output that's shown in browser?

Comment: the file itself, although there will be a fair amount of html tags in it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you look into SimpleXML for parsing your html, this certainly isnt a job for sscanf or worse: regex.

Comment: can simplexml parse .php files?

Comment: No... Don't even.. I'm hoping you're just confusing a server executed php file with the html output (the one with div's).

Comment: i guess the contents of a .php is a more accurate way of explaining it. would that work?

Comment: Please explain your requirements more exactly, this is just going to turn in circles until i have a better picture.

Comment: i've made some changes to the question. not sure if it is clear enough. will try to write some it and use var_dump() to see what i can figure out here soon.